# How to find a string from a txt file and print the very next string after that in python

Tags: python, string

Can anyone tell me how to find a string or word from a text file and then print the next element.
f = open("E:Test.txt", "r")
 if 'feel' in f:
    print('true')

Comment: What is "element"?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show the code and pinpoint exactly where your problem seems to be?

Comment: f = open("E:Test.txt", "r") 
if 'feel' in f: print('true')

Answer (score 1):

Regex is probably the best option here.
My short test file contained the following:
`feel different`

For python 2.4:

```
>>> import re
>>> match_pattern = r'(<=?\bfeel\b)\s+\w+\b'
>>> f=open('E:Test.txt','r')
>>> ftext=f.read()
>>> f.close()
>>> [found.strip() for found in re.findall(match_pattern, ftext)]
['different']
```

For python 2.7 onwards:

```
>>> import re
>>> match_pattern = r'(<=?\bfeel\b)\s+\w+\b'
>>> with open('E:Test.txt','r') as f:
>>>     ftext=f.read()
>>> [found.strip() for found in re.findall(match_pattern, ftext)]
['different']
```

This regex does a lookbehind for the word "feel" and returns any whitespace plus the next word.  We then strip that whitespace off all returned results.

Comment: whats the difference between and python 2.7 and 3.6

Comment: i am beginner so please ignore any mistake

Comment: I believe the code posted for 2.7 onwards should be fine in 3.6.  I tested it here:
https://www.python.org/shell/